# const-correctness compile-errors to invalid conversion error in template function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I built a function that unpeels a single offset number *offset* to an index-array *rindex*. I use that to get the respective indices for higher-dimensional grids. Admittedly, the function looks a bit quirky with its reverse_iterators, but it works and I don't now how to do it differently.

Now, once I make the *bounds* variable const-qualified, I get a very cryptic compile-time error regarding reverse_iterators. Can anybody help me a bit?

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
template <typename size_type, typename crIt, typename rIt>
constexpr size_type unpeel(size_type offset, const crIt rbegin, const crIt rend,
                           rIt rindex) {
  for (rIt rit = rbegin; rit != rend; rit++) {
    *rindex++ = offset % *rit;
    offset /= *rit;
  }
  return offset;
}

int main() {
  size_t count = 0;
  constexpr size_t N = 2;
  const std::array<size_t, N> bounds{{2, 3}};
  std::array<size_t, N> index{};
  unpeel(0, bounds.rbegin(), bounds.rend(), index.rbegin());
}
```

Here the example with the error:
https://ideone.com/nSLPaw

Comment: Is this a compiler error, or an exception? "Throws" seems to imply a run-time exception, but "const-correctness" generally results in compile-time errors.

Comment: 'rit' is a non-constant reverse iterator (in the sense that it can modify the object it points to), 'rbegin' is a constant reverse iterator (in the sense that it can't modify the object it points to). In the initialization of your for loop line 6 you initialize a non-constant reverse iterator with a constant reverse iterator. Try turning "for(rIt..." into "for(crIt..." ( https://ideone.com/7Jo2Ry ) ?

Comment: but if rit is constant, how can it be incremented by rit++ in the 3rd part of the for-loop preamble?

Comment: @JonasK Dammit, I knew "constant" would be misleading here. In fact, I'm not talking about the keyword "const" here but about "iterator" and "const_iterator" which are two different types and in particular a const_iterator never is a "const    iterator". Container classes provide those two types, both can be incremented or otherwise mutated, but const_iterators don't allow you to mutate the object it points to. Basically, if your iterator type was int*, your const_iterator type would be const int* (understand "(const int)*") and "const iterator" would be int* const (understand "const (int*)")

Comment: In fact, rbegin even is a const (keyword-const, ie doesn't allow you to modify rbegin) constant iterator (ie doesn't allow you to modify *rbegin). Same for rend. The const keywords in the signature of the function aren't actually helpful since you're taking things by value already, but they aren't necessarily harmful either. If you remove them from your code you should have exactly the same error. It really stems from that small "c" in "crbegin()" which you used before your edit which means "take the const version of the iterator"

Comment: You're trying to get a non-const pointer from a const pointer, which would allow to to potentially violate const correctness. Declare `rit` as `crIt rit = rbegin` instead

Comment: Oh, ok. Yeah, it works now thanks. Totally missed this.

Comment: _"I get a very cryptic compile-time error"_ Being cryptic to you is not an excuse for not quoting it in full in your question. It may not be cryptic at all to other readers and may reduce the work they must do to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iterator `rbegin` isn't assignable to `rit` - you'll want to declare it as a constant iterator (or simply `auto`) instead:

```
for (auto rit = rbegin; rit != rend; rit++)
```

Since you're passing by value, you could simply

```
while (rbegin != rend) {
  *rindex++ = offset % *rbegin;
   offset /= *rbegin++;
}
```

---

Full, successfully-compiling, code:

```
template <typename size_type, typename InputIterator, typename OutputIterator>
constexpr size_type unpeel(size_type offset,
                           InputIterator rbegin,
                           InputIterator rend,
                           OutputIterator rindex)
{
    for (; rbegin != rend;  ++rbegin) {
        *rindex++ = offset % *rbegin;
        offset /= *rbegin;
    }
    return offset;
}

#include <array>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    constexpr size_t N = 2;
    const std::array<size_t, N> bounds{{2, 3}};
    std::array<size_t, N> index{};
    unpeel(0, bounds.rbegin(), bounds.rend(), index.rbegin());
}
```

I've used the conventional type names for the iterator template types, to make the requirements clearer.